# How to validate uniqueness in Rails 3 Model if I want to check if there is a 2-field combination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I want to know if there is a way in Rails 3, in which I can validate the uniqueness of 2 fields that goes in combination.

The logic goes this way:

I have two fields `employee_code` and `date_entry`.

- Case 1: If the `employee_code` and `date_entry` combination already exist it won't allow to save another record with the same `employee_code` and `date_entry`.
- Case 2: If the `employee_code` and `date_entry` exists but not on the same record, it will allow to save the field.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :employee_code, :scope => [:date_entry]
```

Three and more columns, all you need to do is add elements to the scope list:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :employee_code, :scope => [:date_entry, :another_column]
```

or Rails 3:

```
validates :employee_code, :uniqueness => {:scope => :date_entry}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is for Rails 3:

To do this with just 2 columns, you can just do something like:

> validates :empcode, :uniqueness => {:scope => :date_entry}

For more than 2 columns you can do something like:

> validates :empcode, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:date_entry, :description]}